# Saving scores using FQL

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I've hit upon [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/scores/) which explains how to use the Graph API to save and read scores.

However,I haven't found an equivalent in FQL documentation anywhere. Does this exist in FQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, an FQL-based scores tool is not available.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Facebook - if you're reading this - this could be very handy